# Intellij only wrap chained methods [if no shorter than 3] when formatting code in Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, formatting, intellij-15

I like to wrap long chained methods in my code when i format it. But i don't like method chains that are small (ex: 3 methods or less) to be wrapped. So i want this to be wrapped:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS).writeTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS).readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
```

but **NOT** this

```
String[] str = object.toString().split(":");
```

Is there anyway in Intellij to can control how long the chain has to be in order for it to be wrapped?

Comment: As far as I know there is not a way to control this by number of chained calls. There is an option in the settings (Editor/Code style/Java/Wrapping and Braces/Chained method calls) which can be set to _Wrap if long_. IntelliJ determines what is "long" by Right margin (Settings/Editor/Code style). So if you have right margin set to 80 characters and the chained method call exceeds this length, it will be wrapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is NOT possible on the latest version of Intellij Idea, however you may want to submit a feature request [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new).